# Best way to create a console menu C++

Tags: c++

So I'm making a simple console project using data structures but the thing here I want to know which way will be the best for implementing a console Menu, I want to know what is the best practice for it, this is my actual menu

```
void MainMenu(){
  while(1) 
{
    int opt;

    cout << endl << "----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl << "      Main Menu   " << endl;
    cout << endl << "----------------------------" << endl;

    cin >> opt;
    cout << "\n" << endl;

    switch (opt) 
    {
        case 1:
            SubMenu();
            break;
        case 2:
            //Code
            break;
        case 0:
            exit(1);
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And a submenu example would be this one

```
void Submenu()
{
bool exit=true;
while(exit) 
{
   int opt;

   cout << endl << "----------------------------" << endl;
   cout << endl << "      SubMenu   " << endl;
   cout << endl << "----------------------------" << endl;
   cin >> opt;


    switch (opt) 
        {
          case 1:
            //Code
            break;
          case 0:
                exit = false;
        }

}
```

I want to know if this is a good way of implementing a menu or if there's a better way to do it, also I would like to know where can I find books or documentation in order to code in a proper way to make my program not to use a lot of resources from the PC.

Comment: Ncurses would be *my* choice - possibly in the form of [dialog](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) if you just want something easy, simple and good looking.

Comment: Hmm, well [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html) might help you to create more sophisticated stuff for a terminal UI in a portable way.

Comment: IIRC [Midnight Commander](https://midnight-commander.org/) is a good example how you can create lightweight GUIs with ncurses.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/pmbarrett314/curses-menu

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, table driven console menus are very good.
They allow for constant data (which can be stored in Read-Only Memory).
They are data driven (you don't need to add code to add more options).
The "engine" or driver can be tested once; if you use the same structure, you can use one function to process many menus.

```cpp
    typedef void (*Menu_Processing_Function_Pointer)(void);
    
    struct Menu_Option
    {
      char choice;
      char const * p_selection_text;
      Menu_Processing_Function_Pointer p_processing_function;
    };
    
    void Process_Selection_One();
    void Process_Selection_Two();
    
    static const Menu_Option main_menu[] =
    {
      {'1', "Option 1", Process_Selection_One},
      {'2', "Option 2", Process_Selection_Two},
    };
    static const size_t quantity_selections =
        sizeof(main_menu) / sizeof(main_menu[0]);
    
    int main()
    {
      static const char menu_title = 
        "\n"
        "------------------------------\n"
        "         Main Menu\n"
        "------------------------------\n"
        ;
      cout.write(menu_title, sizeof(menu_title) - 1);
      for (size_t i = 0; i < quantity_selections; ++i)
      {
        std::cout << main_menu[i].p_selection_text << "\n";
      }
      cout << "Enter selection, 0 to quit: ";
      char choice;
      cin >> choice;
      for (size_t i = 0; i < quantity_selections; ++i)
      {
         if (choice == main_menu[i].choice)
         {
           Menu_Processing_Function_Pointer p_function = main_menu[i].p_processing_function;
           (p_function)();
           break;
         }
      }
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

You'll have to implement looping for when the selection is invalid.
The above is the gist of the technique.

Comment: What about KISS-Principle

Comment: Please clarify.  Compare this strategy when developing multiple menus or menus for embedded systems (where dynamic memory allocation is evil).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The code throws compilation error saying `Unknown type name 'Menu_Procesing_Function_Pointer'; did you mean 'Menu_Processing_Function_Pointer'? (fix available)` and `Cannot initialize a variable of type 'const char' with an lvalue of type 'const char [83]'`

Comment: This is KISS when you have to add multiple choices and have multiple menus.  Again, the code to process the data structure only needs to be tested once.  You can add more to the data structure without having to retest the code.

Answer (score -1):

i Would use other loops then switch case:

```
void MainMenu(){
    char coice='';
    while(coice !='#') 
    {
        int opt;

        cout << endl << "----------------------------" << endl;
        cout << endl << "      Main Menu   " << endl;
        cout << endl << "----------------------------" << endl;

        cin >> opt;
        cout << "\n" << endl;

        if(coice =='1') 
        {
            SubMenu();
        }
        if(coice =='2') 
        {
            //Code
        }
    }
    exit(1);
}
```

As far as you dont chose to end die Programm aktively it wont be end and its more clean.

The same way you can make your submenu, if you want.

Comment: Where's your `switch` case?

Comment: Your loop is missing a terminating '}'.

Comment: Is Switch Case necessary? Is not possiblet to do it with a while?

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your first sentence.